# python - how to parse xml with different hierarchies and by specifying only 'name'

Tags: python, xml

I'm learning xml parsing and Python and trying to write a function that allows me to only specify 'name' and it can search through my xml and return the text value.

Currently, my function is restricted to search only through 'GeneralSettings':

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('template.xml')

    def getValues(tree, category):
        for prop_node in tree.iterfind("FileTemplate/properties/obj[@name='GeneralSettings']/properties/prop[@name='%s']" % category):
            return prop_node.text

    print getValues(tree, 'FilePattern')
```

Is there any good technique where I can just write one function by passing in only search 'name' and it can automatically search for everything under root like in unix, 'find . -name'? For example, if I call get text value for "useelapsedtime", can I use same function to just tell it to search for name=useelapsedtime?

My xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<autostart version="2.0">
<FileState>0</FileState>
<FileTemplate clsid="{6F6FBFC1-3F14-46CA-A269}">
<properties>
    <obj name="TypeSettings" clsid="{6F6FBFC1-3F14-46CA-A269}">
        <properties>
            <prop name="Enumerator" type="8">en0</prop>
            <prop name="Name" type="8">en0</prop>
            <prop name="Type" type="3">1</prop>
        </properties>
    </obj>
    <obj name="GeneralSettings" clsid="{6F6FBFC1-3F14-46CA-A269}">
        <properties>
            <prop name="BufferSize" type="21">524288000</prop>
            <prop name="FilePattern" type="8">auto_eth0</prop>
        </properties>
    </obj>
    <obj name="NiCSettings" clsid="{6F6FBFC1-3F14-46CA-A269}">
        <properties>
            <prop name="interface" type="21">eth0</prop>
        </properties>
    </obj>
    <obj name="Trigger" clsid="{E801FFF9-AE26-4DD7-A349">
        <trigger enabled="0" notify="1" severity="0" togglecapture="1">
            <triggerevents>
                <triggereventobj clsid="{EC5E8097-B3D5-4B8D-AA64}">
                    <triggerevent use="0" useelapsedtime="0" time="0" enabled="0" />
                </triggereventobj>
            </triggerevents>
        </trigger>
    </obj>
</properties>
   </FileTemplate>
```

Comment: have a look at the lxml package and it's xpath() method.

Comment: Is this really your XML? It's not actually valid XML. Notice the non-closed `autostart` tag at the beginning? Perhaps that is supposed to close, or supposed to be an attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use `tree.iterfind(".//*[@name='%s']"%name)`.

Breaking it down:

`tree` is the starting node. In this case, the root Element of your parse.

`.` means that the XPATH description starts with `tree`.

`//` means to recurse any number of levels

`*` means to consider any tag

`[@name='foo']` means to consider only elements with attributes named foo

`%s` means to substitue the value of a variable into the string

So:

`tree.iterfind(".//*[@name='%s']"%name)` means:

- Starting at `tree`,
- and going through every level,
- find any element, regardless of its tag name,
- with an attribute named `name`,
- which attribute has a value equal to the contents of the variable `name`.